# ListView with buttons OnClickListener?

Tags: android, listview, button, click

I am working on app with ListView with buttons on list item.
It's working fine but I can't find way to make buttons on items clickable.
[image]

I want to make this Silver arrows clickable. How can I do that?

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="btnclick"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
How can I make this to be different, like ItemClickListener with position?
```

Here is my Adapter

```
  class DAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context context;
    int [] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    DAdapter(Context c, String [] titles, int imgs[])

    {
        super(c,R.layout.single_row, R.id.title,titles);
        this.context=c;
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray=titles;
            }


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;
    if (row==null) {        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent,false);
    }
    ImageView myImage=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView myTitle=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);



    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);

    return row;
```

I'm not sure if I should add whole code but if its needed please tell me.

single_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="btnclick"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post R.layout.single_row layout code..

Comment: Why do you want to make **only** the arrow clickable? Would having the whole row clickable solve the problem as well?

Comment: It is clickable, but lets say whole row is playing media player, arrow is showing some menu or starts new activity

Comment: You can use on click listener on each item in list view

Comment: How can I do that? Can you write code in an answer?
I tried something but It didn't work

Comment: @Sabroan we will write if you provide a single_row xml file..

Comment: @Sabroan posted change like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add id to your ImageView like..

```
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
    android:onClick="btnclick"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

then get the ImageView and write listener ..change your getView like..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    ImageView arrowImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.arrowImage);
    arrowImage.setTag(position);
    arrowImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int clickedposition=(Integer) v.getTag();
            //Write your Activity launch code here..
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Comment: How can I set this for multiple rows? Do I need something like case?

Comment: Um Lets say I have 10 rows and that ImageView is used to start new activity or do something else when clicked. How can I define that? 
Start...3rd activity when clicked on 3rd row ImageView

Comment: @Sabroan you are likely extending your question..ok..for that you need maintaing tags which is cliked..based on that position you need to start the Activity..

Comment: @Sabroan have you tried my code..and is your onClick is working??Firrst try that

Comment: Yes. _How can I make this to be different, like ItemClickListener with position?_

Comment: I see. This is working btw. I just tested it, now all its left to determine position clicked. Thanks man

Comment: @Sabroan i just edited my GetView code..change like that..you will get the position clicked..

Comment: This worked!! Thanks man. I just added in addition to your code: `switch (position) {
         case 0: 
break;`

And it's working as I wanted it to!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set a general onclick handler for the image view. Then while doing the job in the onclick listener just check its parent to know the parent of this button. And if you want some custom style for this arrow to be shown, you can use a button instead of imageButton and set its background to an xml file to make it dynamic.
Is this enough?

Comment: Yes. I can change it to button it's no problem, but how can I set position clicked? Something like ItemClickListener with Switch case
`AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
`